# How to restore deleted audio files from media library

Tags: audio, customization

I accidentally deleted my audio files from the media library. Is it possible to restore them

Comment: Unless you have a backup system or system to prevent those kind of things, there is nothing you can do, WordPress doesn't prevent those things.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is a hard drive recovery if you don't have backups.